# Debian - mdadm: No devices listed in conf file were found

Tags: debian, mdadm

after an update and restart my Debian, in which I have configure RAID 1, I am getting the following error:

```
> i8042: No Controller found Loading, please wait... mdadm: No devices
> listed in conf file were found. Gave up waiting for root device.
> Common problems:
>  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
>    - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
>    - Check root=(did the system wait for the right device?)
> - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev) ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/4b8b657b-ed18-4ff1-8734-3240934adsd does not exist.
> Dropping to a shell! modprobe: module ehci-orion not found in
> modules.dep
```

The is loading BusyBox.

Comment: Firstly, how did you upgrade Debian?  Secondly, check boot parameters which is set in loader conf. Maybe some parameters is omitted. Thirdly, how  is initrd.img beeing created?

Comment: Hi, I have upgrade the packages not the distro version, througt apt-update and apt-upgrade. Secondly, which loader ??? Third I don't know what do you mean.

Comment: Hi, about secondly, maybe apt has upgraded kernel and therefore has update loader (i.e. GRUB) config. So, if you have just used apt, then third question may be omitted (I thought that you build your custom initrd).

Comment: Others things I can check @YurijGoncharuk?

Comment: Load system with old kernel. Then, find in '/boot/grub/grub.cfg' (i.e. in Debian 9 this file is placed there) menuentry of your old kernel (on which you successful run soft RAID). Check all parameters in the line that begins from word 'kernel' and ensure that this parameters also set in menuentry for your updated kernel. You may see values like this: root=/dev/md0 md=0,/dev/sda1,/dev/sdc1.

Comment: @YurijGoncharuk in the busybox I cannot find the /boot/grub/grub.cfg,, there are no boot folder!

Comment: Off cause you can't see boot folder in initrd environment. You must restart machine and from boot menu chose your old worked version. If boot menu doesn't show, than it's need to boot from LiveCD and mount soft RAID by itself. After, you can see all your configuration that belong to not working system.

Comment: This is what we search - https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.14/admin-guide/md.html#boot-time-assembly-of-raid-arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73144/discussion-between-kostasc-and-yurij-goncharuk).